# ColdFusion: Minify XML

Tags: coldfusion, minify, coldfusion-8

I have various bits of XML creation going on. One such cut down example is:

```
<cfxml variable="xmlDoc">
    <cfoutput>
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
        <event id="#iEventId#">
            <relatedevents>
                <cfloop query="qPreviousEvents">
                    <cfif eventid IS NOT iEventId>
                        <event id="#eventid#" sameyear="<cfif DateFormat(startdate, " yyyy ") EQ DateFormat(cfcObject.GetStartDate(), "yyyy ")>1<cfelse>0</cfif>">
                            <title>#XmlFormat(Title)#</title>
                            <tag>#LCase(ReReplaceNoCase(ReReplaceNoCase(tagname, " ", "-", "all"), "[^a-z0-9_-]", "", "all"))#</tag>
                        </event>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </relatedevents>
        </event>
    </cfoutput>
</cfxml>
<cfreturn xmlDoc>
```

My question is how the resulting XML can be minified? At the moment there are blank lines where the CF is and a row for each node. Ideally I'd like it to be be minified so it's only on one line with no space between tags.

Could I do a replace somewhere or is there a function I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Rather than put the indentation in then take it back out again, perhaps best to not put it in in the first place.

A reasonably expedient (if slightly inelegant) way of doing this could be to suppress output except for when you stipulate it, eg:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<cfxml variable="x">
    <cfoutput><aaa></cfoutput>
        <cfoutput><bbb/></cfoutput>
        <cfoutput><ccc ddd="eee">fff<ggg /></ccc></cfoutput>
    <cfoutput></aaa></cfoutput>
</cfxml>

<pre>
<cfoutput>#encodeForHtml(toString(x))#</cfoutput>    <!--- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <aaa><bbb/><ccc ddd="eee">fff<ggg/></ccc></aaa> ----> 
</pre>
```

Comment: `encodeForHTML()` got added with CF10 - question is tagged with CF8. Just for info, if op is wondering why your example throws an error.

Comment: Good call. Obviously (?) my code - and especially that part of it - is just meant for demonstration purposes. But this in no way invalidates what you say.